# Two Sites or One Site When building a CMS Type Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, content-management-system

I'm building a site which mainly has articles and I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. I want to have an admin page where I can add, edit these article content.

I'm building **one site** for both content management(Add articles) and display content(Display articles).

Are there any disadvantages with this approach? (Do I have to build one site for content management and another site to display content?)

Comment: Short answer - no you don't have to. You can view and edit your content on one site as you cant see in on SO.

Comment: @teovankot Is that the common and best approach?

Comment: Your question is opinion based. There is no best approach

Comment: @teovankot Can you give me some resources about this. I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a separate project for the administration portal is valid if you have a security policy implying that administration pages must be only accessible by operations team over VPN or from intranet (not exposed to the internet). Otherwise, it is valid to have them hosted on the same site.